# Print PDF docs from web form

Tags: asp.net, pdf, printing

Is there some kind of light-weight (non-Adobe) control I could use to view and print PDF documents on a web form?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you talking about a server-based control to view PDF or just a client viewer?  Your comment to Richard John suggests the former...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [Foxit](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/rd_intro.php).  Lightweight - loads faster than Adobe.

Answer (score 2):

ABCPdf is a free PDF generator for ASP.NET; all you have to do is link back to their site if you use it.

http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-1.htm

Answer (score 1):

[Flashpaper](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashpaper/), it is platform independant.

The reason I suggest this is that you can embed PDF viewing right in any web-browser via this Flash Plugin (and print), but never have to have  PDF viewing software installed or configured to work with the web browser.

**Edit: As per the comment, new Flashpaper versions have been discontinued.  Flashpaper will continue to be available for sale though. (see link in comment).**  I have used it for several years and haven't found much of a need for new features, but your case may differ.  Try it out.

Comment: .. but still selling it.  They just won't be making new features. (From link) "Will Adobe continue to sell FlashPaper? Adobe will continue to sell the current FlashPaper 2 version.".. If only they would have stopped developing Acrobat and kept selling it. We'd have 3 second load times for Acrobat 5!

Answer (score 0):

[Foxit Reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/reader/) is more lightweight than the Adobe Reader.

Answer (score 0):

For displaying a PDF, you could use [PDF Me Not](http://pdfmenot.com/tools/).
I'm not sure if you mean generating a PDF of a form submission, though. If this is what you meant, there are PDF libraries for just about every language (such as [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) for PHP).

For the first case, there's also [AlivePDF](http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/) which is open source.

Comment: I'm exporting PDF from a telerik RadGrid, but the end user doesn't want to have to export and then open the file to print it.  They just want to click a print button.

Answer (score 0):

[Aspose.com](http://www.aspose.com/) can do some pretty nifty stuff for .NET and Java

Comment: Too bad it's $1800 for a single developer license.

Comment: or just $600 for the part you need :) But still expensive

Answer (score 0):

phpLiveDocx and LiveDocx are completely free and can be used to merge data (for example, from a web form) with a template from MS Word or Open Office on the server.

- phpLiveDocx runs on Linux, Windows and Mac.
- LiveDocx runs on Windows.

Learn more at:

- http://www.phplivedocx.org/articles/brief-introduction-to-phplivedocx/
- http://www.livedocx.com